# Eclipse's Window Builder missing Design

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, import, windowbuilder

I have a simple Eclipse Java project that consists in only one Class made with Eclipse's Window Builder (Swing class). The coding was made on my notebook, and saved on cloud, so I could access It from my home's computer.
When I opened this project in this home computer, I noticed I had not installed Window Builder on it yet, so I installed and restarted Eclipse.

The problem is that even tho I installed WB, Eclipse still doesn't show the *Design* tab on this class. Did I miss something?

Comment: Right click on the file and look in the 'Open With...' menu

Answer (score 1):

Simply restarting Eclipse a couple times somehow made it work, everything good!

Answer (score 0):

**Missing Source/Design tabs**

When you open your Swing Project, follow these steps to show Source/Design tab:

- Right click on your file `Swing.java` for example
- Choose open with `Window Builder editor`

This will bring you back the `Source` and `Design` Panels